# Bootstrap 4.5 scaffolding not showing as expected

Tags: layout, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, scaffolding

I'm trying to make a 2 columns layout with bootstrap 4.5
It should display as 2 columns when seen on larger display, then in smaller display the different divs should be stacked in 1 column. I followed the "Nesting columns" section of this example: https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html

This is my aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="MainPage.aspx.vb" Inherits="Efesto_2.MainPage" ValidateRequest="false" Culture="it-IT" UICulture="it-IT" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Efesto</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/fontawesome-all.min.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowPopup() {
            $("#btnShowPopup").click();
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableScriptGlobalization="true" EnableScriptLocalization="true" EnablePartialRendering="false"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top text-white">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="MainPage.aspx" runat="server" id="MenuHome">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="Clienti.aspx" runat="server" id="MenuClienti">Clienti</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="MenuChiamate" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Chiamate
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="RichiesteEmail.aspx">Richieste Email</a>
                            <asp:LinkButton class="dropdown-item" runat="server" ID="lnkNuovaChiamata" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="javascript:window.open('chiamata.aspx?RFRic=0&id=0&azione=inserisci','_blank','left=20,top=20,width=620,height=700,status=no, menubar=no, toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=1');">INSERISCI NUOVA</asp:LinkButton>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="ElencoChiamate.aspx">Elenco chiamate</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="kanban.aspx">Attività</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="Interventi.aspx">Interventi</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="MenuMagazzino" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Magazzino
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="GestioneProdotti.aspx">Gestione prodotti</a>
                            <%--<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton1" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="javascript:window.open('chiamata.aspx?RFRic=0&id=0&azione=inserisci','_blank','left=20,top=20,width=620,height=700,status=no, menubar=no, toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=1');">INSERISCI NUOVA</asp:LinkButton>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="ElencoChiamate.aspx">Elenco chiamate</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="kanban.aspx">Attività</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="Interventi.aspx">Interventi</a>--%>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="VulcanoPage.aspx">Vulcano</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <asp:LinkButton class="nav-link" Text="Logout" runat="server" ID="btnLogout" OnClick="btnLogout_Click" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="MenuStrumenti" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="padding-right: 8em;">Strumenti
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="ModuloServizi.aspx" target="_blank">Modulo Servizi</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <%--<form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>--%>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" runat="server" id="divAlert" style="display: none;">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close" onclick="chiudiAlert();">&times;</a>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAlertTitolo" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label><br />
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAlertMessaggio"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div style="padding: 2rem; padding-top: 6rem;">
                    <div class="row">
                            <div class="span9">
                                <div class="col9">
                                <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header">
                                    <i class="fa fa-id-card fa-2x fa-pull-left"></i>
                                    <h4 class="card-title">Chiamate giorno</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <div>
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtData" Type="date" ToolTip="Data" required="required" AutoPostBack="true" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUtenti" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" CssClass="tendina tendina-auto" ToolTip="Scegli tecnico" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlUtenti_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Tutti</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </div>

                                    <br />
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <div id="divChiamateGiorno" class="scrollDiv">
                                            <asp:GridView ID="grdChiamateGiorno" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="idchia,dalle,alle,idstato" DataSourceID="SqlChiamateGiorno" AllowSorting="True" CssClass="tablestyle">
                                                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="WhiteSmoke" CssClass="altrowstyle altezzaMinima" Height="50px" Width="100%" />
                                                <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" />
                                                <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" BackColor="LightGray" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Height="30px" CssClass="headerstyle" />
                                                <RowStyle CssClass="rowstyle altezzaMinima" Height="50px" />

                                                <Columns>
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="tecnico" HeaderText="Tecnico" SortExpression="tecnico" />
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ragsoc" HeaderText="Cliente" SortExpression="ragsoc" ItemStyle-Width="30%" />
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="rdescr" HeaderText="Richiesta" SortExpression="rdescr" ItemStyle-Width="50%" />
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="prior" HeaderText="Priorità" SortExpression="prior" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="app" HeaderText="Appuntamento" SortExpression="app" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="assremota" HeaderText="Remoto" SortExpression="assremota" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Classif" HeaderText="Class." SortExpression="Classif" ItemStyle-Font-Bold="true" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="idchia" HeaderText="idchia" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="idchia" Visible="false" />
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="tipo" HeaderText="tipo" SortExpression="tipo" Visible="false" />
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="rforo" HeaderText="rforo" SortExpression="rforo" Visible="false" />
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="dalle" HeaderText="dalle" SortExpression="dalle" Visible="false" />
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="alle" HeaderText="alle" SortExpression="alle" Visible="false" />
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="idstato" HeaderText="idstato" SortExpression="idstato" Visible="false" />
                                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Bloccato" HeaderText="Bloccato" SortExpression="Bloccato" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="5%">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <div class="tooltip">
                                                                <i id="collapse3" runat="server" class="fa fa-caret-square-o-left fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                                <span class="tooltiptext" style="width: 170px;" id="litGestioneGiorn" runat="server"></span>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                </Columns>
                                            </asp:GridView>
                                        </div>

                                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlChiamateGiorno" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbVulcanoConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="select utenti.nome as tecnico, Richieste.IDRic as idchia, richieste.descr as rdescr, ISNULL(richieste.assistremota,0) as assremota, Clienti.RagSociale as ragsoc, richieste.descr as descr, richieste.priorita as prior, richieste.tipo as tipo, richieste.rforologio as rforo, ISNULL(statoric.appuntamento,0) as app, ISNULL(statoric.oradalle,0) as dalle, ISNULL(statoric.oraalle,0) as alle, statoric.ID as idstato, left(isnull(Clienti.punta,''),2) as classif, right(left(isnull(Clienti.punta,''),3),1) as Bloccato from clienti inner join richieste on clienti.idcliente = richieste.rfcliente inner join statoric on statoric.rfric = richieste.idric inner join stati on stati.idstato = statoric.rfstato inner join utenti on utenti.idutente=statoric.rftecnico where statoric.attuale = 1 and (statoric.rfstato &lt; 14 or statoric.rfstato=41) and statoric.dataass = @data and (@tecnico = -1 or statoric.rftecnico = @tecnico) order by app desc, oraalle asc, prior desc"><%--statoric.dataass between @data and coalesce(@data2, @data)--%>
                                            <SelectParameters>
                                                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtData" DefaultValue="17/01/2017" Name="data" PropertyName="Text" Type="DateTime" />
                                                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlUtenti" DefaultValue="0" Name="tecnico" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                                            </SelectParameters>
                                        </asp:SqlDataSource>
                                        <p>
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </p>
                                        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td></td>
                                                <td align="right">
                                                    <asp:Button runat="server" name="Stampa" type="button" class="gbutton" ID="btnStampa" Text="Stampa" />
                                                    <%--onclick="printdiv('divChiamateGiorno');" --%>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row" style="padding-top: 1rem;">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <div class="card">
                                        <div class="card-header">
                                            <i class="fa fa-id-card fa-2x fa-pull-left"></i>
                                            <h4 class="card-title">Calendario</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="span3">
                                <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-header">
                                                <i class="fa fa-id-card fa-2x fa-pull-left"></i>
                                                <h4 class="card-title">Consuntivazione rapida</h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 1rem;">
                                        <div class="col-12">
                                            <div class="card">
                                                <div class="card-header">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-id-card fa-2x fa-pull-left"></i>
                                                    <h4 class="card-title">Chiamate aperte</h4>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="card-body">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 1rem;">
                                        <div class="col-12">
                                            <div class="card">
                                                <div class="card-header">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-id-card fa-2x fa-pull-left"></i>
                                                    <h4 class="card-title">Attività</h4>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="card-body">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<%-- PER APRIRE I MENU DELLA NAVBAR SUL MOUSEOVER --%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".dropdown, .btn-group").hover(function () {
            var dropdownMenu = $(this).children(".dropdown-menu");
            if (dropdownMenu.is(":visible")) {
                dropdownMenu.parent().toggleClass("open");
            }
        });
    });     
</script>

<script>
    function chiudiAlert() {
        __doPostBack('chiudiAlert');
    }
</script>
```

and this is what I get:
[image]

and this what I want:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I ended up using container-fluid and col-lg